# Why is sadaari not placed for new borns?

Tags: practice, vaishnavism

Why sadaari is not placed for new borns?
Eager to know the reason.

Comment: Could you mention how old the newborn baby is? There are some common practices that the newborn does not leave the house until it’s in the third lunar month, and the first visit is to the temple. (Nowadays we make exceptions for medical visits.)

Comment: Shataari and thiruman are not done for the whole 1st year. Till 1st year choulam/mundan (hair cut), it is considered unclean. Also, I read somewhere that it takes Brahma a tiny instant of time to write the baby's fortune (thalai-ezuthu), and that instant in brahma loka translates to 1 human year on earth. Not sure if this second part has scriptural basis.